# Conditional operator to initalize one of two variables

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I know one can do something like this to initalise an integer variable depending on a specific condition:

```
boolean myCond = getCond();
int x = myCond ? 13 : 42;
```

But is there a way to use the conditional operation to choose one of two variables? An equivalent of following if-else

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

if(myCond){
   x = 13;
}
else{
   y = 13;
}
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that you wouldn't be able to use either of those variables after your if/else, because they're not definitely assigned.

Comment: @AndyTurner Edited. I hope that was what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign the initial/other value based on the condition:

```
int x = myCond ? 13 : 0;
int y = !myCond ? 13 : 0;
```

You have to definitely assign the variables in order to use them at all (if they are local variables).

---

I suppose you could do it like:

```
int unused = myCond ? (x = 13) : (y = 13);
```

but that's an abuse of syntax, because you have to introduce that unused variable in order to make a statement out of the conditional expression.

Comment: I'd add that option from question itself is actually best one

Comment: Did that mean the initial values have to be the same? Or is there a way to say update only one and dont touch the other?

Comment: @IłyaBursov I wouldn't say it's absolutely the best: it does have the downside of reassigning the variables, meaning they're not effectively final.

Comment: @nopens the values when the condition isn't met to "assign" the variable can be whatever you want. They're just 0/0 here because that's what you have in the question.

Comment: @AndyTurner true, probably `final int x, y; if(myCond) {x=13;y=0;}else{x=0;y=13;}` is better then

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to allocate and intialize the two variables anyway, do so to satisfy the `!myCond` condition.  Then the other condition is all that is needed.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 13;

if(myCond){
   x = 13;
   y = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers: the reason you can't write an assignment like

```
   (cond ? x : y) = 13;
```

is because [the Java language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) says you can't.

If you look at the definition of an **assignment statement** in 15.26, the left-hand side of an assignment operator is quite limited in what's allowed. Simplifying the discussion a little, it's either an identifier (i.e., assignment to a simple variable), an array access (i.e., assignment to an array element), or a field access (i.e., assignment to a member variable).

Comment: In C, I think you can write `*(cond ? &x : &y) = 13;` if you must, but Java doesn't allow permit references to primitives or other references.